# How to pin a package version with `nix-shell`?

Tags: shell, configuration, version, nix

From what I understand, I can use a given version of Nix packages using the `-I` flag. But I would like to know if it is possible within a single `shell.nix` conf to have something like:

- `git` v2.1.2
- `htop` v1.2.3
- ...

to be able to ensure given tools versions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are several ways to do this, but none of them are as direct and simple as `git v2.1.2; htop v1.2.3` and come with a lot of caveats.

> **aside**
> Specifying versions for programming language packages are possible too, but that topic seems to be even messier. The most promising standardization effort to date is [`dream2nix`](https://github.com/nix-community/dream2nix).

### 0. Methods

That is, available at the time of this writing:

#### 0.1 "versioned" attribute paths (if available)

> ###### Single-version policy
>
> We keep multiple versions in nixpkgs only when there's a good reason to. Nix is able to handle any number of versions/configurations, but on the other hand it's much more convenient when all (or most) use just a single one. It leads to better sharing of the effort in many respects: simplified maintenance, testing, sharing of the binaries, etc. It's what most distros do. (Only gentoo diverges from the big ones I know, and they pay a price for it.)
>
> When we do create more variants, we just name them (attribute paths), e.g. `gcc48` and `gcc49` or `ffmpeg` and `ffmpeg-full`.
>
> -- *[vcunat commented on Sep 6, 2015](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/9682#issuecomment-138105069) on [Nixpkgs issue #9682](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/9682)*

Citing [jtojnar's discourse answer](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/specifying-package-version-in-shell-nix/8513/2) for a more specific example:

```
$ nix-env -qP --available nodejs
nixos.nodejs       nodejs-10.18.1
nixos.nodejs-10_x  nodejs-10.18.1
nixos.nodejs-12_x  nodejs-12.14.1
nixos.nodejs-13_x  nodejs-13.6.0
$ nix-env -iA nixos.nodejs-13_x
```

#### 0.2 *Pinning*

Either explicitly or implicitly with

- *Nix derivation expressions* (see Example 2.2)
- Nix command line tools (see Example 2.1)
- overlays
- overrides (see Example 2.3)
- flakes (pinning is the default)
- third party, "unofficial", and/or proprietary methods (e.g., [`niv`](https://github.com/nmattia/niv), [`niv` + Home Manager](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/can-i-pin-package-versions-with-niv-on-home-manager/11471), [flox](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nix/comments/11jwb8y/comment/jb4xdk4/))

### 1. Terms

#### 1.1 Pinning

The best description I could find is in [this comment](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/9682#issuecomment-332404016) by CMCDragonkai; to paraphrase it:

> **Pinning** in a *Nix expression* means to use a *Nix package set* (usually [Nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs) or a fork of it) at a specific point (i.e., in a certain state) of its history.

Using a Git ([content-addressed](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#:%7E:text=Git%20is%20a%20content%2Daddressable%20filesystem.)) commit hash in the [Nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs) repo is similar to being in ["detached HEAD state"](https://www.baeldung.com/git-detached-head#:%7E:text=The%20purpose%20of%20HEAD%20is%20to%20keep%20track%20of%20the%20current%20point%20in%20a%20Git%20repo): from a Nix expression's perspective, every package definition is the latest version at the time the commit was issued.

For example, when referring to the Nixpkgs package set pinned to [`39cd40f`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/commit/39cd40f7bea40116ecb756d46a687bfd0d2e550e) (Sep 29, 2017), the "latest" versions will be:

- [`git`: 2.14.2](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/39cd40f7bea40116ecb756d46a687bfd0d2e550e/pkgs/applications/version-management/git-and-tools/git/default.nix) (current is 2.39.1)
- [`htop`: 2.0.2](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/39cd40f7bea40116ecb756d46a687bfd0d2e550e/pkgs/tools/system/htop/default.nix) (current is 3.2.2)

> **WARNING**
> The Nixpkgs repo tracks both the official Nix package set **and** the convenience tools used in Nix expressions! See Example 2.1 below on how this can break assumptions.

As far as I can tell, the term "pinning" is still not defined in any of the official documentation. (The [Nixpkgs manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/) mentions it once with an example but without explanation.)

#### 1.2 Nix expression

A piece of code written using the [Nix expression language](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/index.html).

#### 1.3 Nix derivation expression

A *Nix expression* that will evaluate to a *Nix derivation* (usually by eventually calling the `derivation` ([source](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/89d3cc5a47a448f624ea4c9b43eeee00dcc88a21/src/libexpr/primops/derivation.nix)) *primop*, most commonly via `mkShell` ([source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/095a5bbfefb4e6cbf363ca283fe0a48c80c8759f/pkgs/build-support/mkshell/default.nix)) or `mkDerivation` ([source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/095a5bbfefb4e6cbf363ca283fe0a48c80c8759f/pkgs/stdenv/generic/default.nix#L159))).

> **note**: *Nix derivation vs Nix derivation expression*
>
> It is easier for me to reason about Nix when making a clear distinction between a *Nix derivation* and code that evaluates to a *Nix derivation* (i.e., Nix derivation expression). Did an attempt to make it clearer in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58243555/1498178), but it needs to updated so take it with a grain of salt.

#### 1.4 Primop

> Primitive operations, or ***primops***, are functions that are built into the language. They need not be defined or imported; they are in scope by default. But since they are normal identifiers, they **can** be overridden by local definitions.
>
> -- [Eelco Dolstra, The Purely Functional Software Deployment Model (PhD thesis)](https://edolstra.github.io/pubs/phd-thesis.pdf) (January 18, 2006)

These are implemented in the [NixOS/nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/) repo.

#### 1.5 Nix derivation

([placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58243555/1498178))

#### 1.6 Package set

See [What are package sets?](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/what-are-package-sets/15474) on the NixOS Discourse, but to paraphrase [ryantm's answer](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/values.html?highlight=attribute%20set#attribute-set):

> **Package set** is a collection of *Nix expression*s that evaluate to an *[attribute set](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/values.html?highlight=attribute%20set#attribute-set)* (also called "attrset") where the names are the names of the packages (or names of recursive **package sets**) and the values are *Nix derivations*.

Examples:

- [Nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs)
- [Nix User Repository (NUR)](https://github.com/nix-community/NUR)
- [ethereum.nix](https://github.com/nix-community/ethereum.nix)
- From nixos.wiki's [Alternative Package Sets](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Alternative_Package_Sets) page:

  - [Nixcrpkgs](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/nixcrpkgs) - Focused on cross-compiling
  - [Triton](https://github.com/triton/triton) - see [differences between Nixpkgs and Triton](https://triton.github.io/triton/triton-vs-nixos.html)
  - [NixWRT](https://github.com/telent/nixwrt/) - Build Router images with nix, based on nixpkgs
- From the [`awesome-nix-hpc`](https://github.com/freuk/awesome-nix-hpc) list:

  - flatiron institute: https://github.com/flatironinstitute/nix-modules
  - gricad: https://github.com/Gricad/nix-ciment-channel
  - blue brain project: https://github.com/BlueBrain/bbp-nixpkgs
  - compute canada: https://github.com/ComputeCanada/nixpkgs/tree/computecanada-16.09
  - compute canada: https://git.computecanada.ca/nix/ccpkgs
  - datamove: https://github.com/oar-team/nur-kapack
  - quantum chemistry packages: https://github.com/markuskowa/NixOS-QChem

### 2. Examples

#### 2.1 Pinning Nixpkgs on `nix-shell` invocation

Compressing a usual Nix-shell expression,

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

pkgs.mkShell {

  buildInputs = [
    pkgs.git
    pkgs.htop
  ];

  shellHook = ''
    echo "git:  $(git  --version)"
    echo "htop: $(htop --version)"
  '';
}
```

into a one-liner, then

```
nix-shell \
-I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/39cd40f7bea40116ecb756d46a687bfd0d2e550e.tar.gz \
-E '{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }: pkgs.mkShell { buildInputs = [ pkgs.git pkgs.htop ]; shellHook = "echo \"git: $(git --version)\"; echo \"htop: $(htop --version)\";"; }'
```

won't work because `mkShell` has not been implemented yet, thus:

```
nix-shell \
-I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/39cd40f7bea40116ecb756d46a687bfd0d2e550e.tar.gz \
-E '{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }: pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation { name = "shell"; buildInputs = [ pkgs.git pkgs.htop ]; shellHook = "echo \"git: $(git --version)\"; echo \"htop: $(htop --version)\";"; }'
```

Notes:

- The only difference between the 2 snippet is that the part `pkgs.mkShell { buildInputs` has been replaced with `pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation { name = "shell"; buildInputs`.
- Ran both commands on Ubuntu 22.04 (`aarch64`); also, the 2nd won't run on `aarch64-darwin`.

#### 2.2 Pin Nixpkgs in a Nix expression

Using [jeff-hykin's comment](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/9682#issuecomment-658424656) as template:

##### Step 0. Find the Version you Want

Find (almost) all versions of a package using [lazamar's absolutely amazing online tool](https://lazamar.co.uk/nix-versions/).

##### Step 1: Install that version using its Hash

Click on the hash in the row for the version you need (e.g., [`git` 2.23.0](https://lazamar.co.uk/nix-versions/?package=git&version=2.23.0&fullName=git-2.23.0&keyName=gitAndTools.gitFull&revision=bca9437d1eae9519b61a58f2593f25f65494f8e9&channel=nixpkgs-unstable#instructions) and [`htop` 2.2.0](https://lazamar.co.uk/nix-versions/?package=htop&version=2.2.0&fullName=htop-2.2.0&keyName=htop&revision=b5e903cedb331f9ee268ceebffb58069f1dae9fb&channel=nixpkgs-unstable#instructions)), and either use the `nix-env`/`nix-shell` commands listed there one-by-one, or copy the Nix expression snippets into a file (and rename to variables to avoid clashes):

```
# git_htop.nixshell

let

  pkgs_for_git = import (builtins.fetchTarball {
    url = "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/bca9437d1eae9519b61a58f2593f25f65494f8e9.tar.gz";
  }) {};

  pkgs_for_htop = import (builtins.fetchTarball {
    url = "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/b5e903cedb331f9ee268ceebffb58069f1dae9fb.tar.gz";
  }) {};

  # Copied lines above from lazamar's tool,
  # but the shortened form works too:
  #
  #   pkgs = import (builtins.fetchTarball "<url>") {};

in
  
  # Chose `pkgs_for_htop` arbitrarily; what matters
  # is that the  derivation function  exists in the
  # pinned Nixpkgs.

  pkgs_for_htop.mkShell {

    buildInputs = [
      pkgs_for_htop.htop
      pkgs_for_git.git
    ];

    shellHook = ''
      echo "git:  $(git  --version)"
      echo "htop: $(htop --version)"
    '';
  }
```

and then call it:

```
nix-shell -v git_htop.nixshell
```

#### 2.3 Specify packages with overlays (stub)

Simply linking [a file from jwiegley's `nix-config` repo](https://github.com/jwiegley/nix-config/blob/c41a8c697c91b459af72b97242575272f98981ab/overlays/00-last-known-good.nix); I don't understand it yet, but wanted to include it anyway.

### 3. Further reading

Online discussions to follow this still evolving topic:

- `github` [Nixpkgs issue #9682 (**closed**): No way to install/use a specific package version?](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/9682)

  Opened in 2015 and even though it is now closed, the issue never got resolved, and the conversation was carried onto the next issue:
- `github` [Nixpkgs issue #93327 (**open**): There isn't a clear canonical way to refer to a specific package version.](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/93327)
- `reddit` [How do I install a specific version of a package in Nix?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nix/comments/11jwb8y/how_do_i_install_a_specific_version_of_a_package/)
- `ycombinator` [This](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=28593823) is the relevant part of the [main thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=28565072).
- `discourse` [Best practice for pinning version of individual packages](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/best-practice-for-pinning-version-of-individual-packages/6194)
- `discourse` [Specifying Package Version in `shell.nix`?](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/specifying-package-version-in-shell-nix/8513)

---

(Hoping to expand this with more examples.)

Comment: The [GitHub gist version](https://gist.github.com/toraritte/62e53be9e6d88d8b6b97391eb3c6558b) of this answer and it is also [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741682/is-it-possible-to-pin-a-package-version-with-nix-shell/744502).

Answer (score 2):

You can import nixpkgs archives with hashes that contain specific package versions. You can find hashes for example [here](https://lazamar.co.uk/nix-versions/)

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { } }:

let
  gitPkgsHash = "0c159930e7534aa803d5cf03b27d5c86ad6050b7"; #git 2.16.2
  htopPkgsHash = "5ed9176c52e4ceed2755a19b3e8357a0772de8ff"; #htop 2.0.0
  gitPkgs = import (fetchTarball "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/${gitPkgsHash}.tar.gz") { };
  htopPkgs = import (fetchTarball "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/${htopPkgsHash}.tar.gz") { };
in

pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = [
    gitPkgs.gitAndTools.gitFull
    htopPkgs.htop
  ];
}
```

PS. In this config i used newer versions, because your version are very old and caused some errors